# Какая грамматическая основа?

Tags: грамматика

В предложении "дымковская игрушка - одно из изделий ручной работы" подлежащее "игрушка" или "дымковская игрушка"? И почему?

Comment: Катя, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Дымковская игрушка** — одно из изделий ручной работы.*

Я считаю, что подлежащим является словосочетание "дымковская игрушка", так как его можно отнести к **синтаксически неделимым словосочетаниям**.

Из вузовского учебника "Синтаксис современного русского языка" (стр.7)    [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

"Синтаксическая неделимость большинства словосочетаний объясняется **семантической недостаточностью** их главного слова. Такое слово самостоятельно не может выполнить функцию конкретизируемого или конкретизирующего компонента словосочетания".

Другими словами, предмет полностью характеризуется словосочетанием, а не одним существительным "игрушка". Аналогичные примеры: *вологодские кружева, жостовская роспись.*